# Giving back fast thread to pool instead of waiting for slow thread

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

We have two individual tasks which we running in parallel and then merging their result. Below code snippet for same. Sometime task1 take more time some task2 take more time. As you can see in merge function first we are getting task1 result and than task2. When task1 take more time even task2 thread remain busy. Is there a way that we can release thread as soon as that task is complete irrespective of other task status.

```
CompletableFuture<List<?>> task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> task1(), threadPoolTaskExecutor);

        CompletableFuture<List<?>> task2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> task2(), threadPoolTaskExecutor);

        final CompletableFuture<List<?>> tasks = CompletableFuture.allOf(task1, task2).thenApply(
                ignore -> Stream.of(task1, task2).map(cf -> cf.join()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // merge two data
        merge((List<DistributorZipCmTntZone>) tasks.join().get(0),
                        (List<DistributorZipCmTntZone>) tasks.join().get(1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ExecutorCompletionService. It implements a queue which receives the tasks as they complete. On your side you write myCompletionService.take().get() and you receive tasks as they finish.